# how to create a timer in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timer, win-universal-app

I am trying to create a timer in C#. None of the usual classes seem to be available from my visual studio project. I have tried all of the following:

```
System.Timers.Timer
System.Windows.Forms.Timer
System.Threading.Timer
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
```

For all of these it says the class can not be found. Here is some sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Game
{
    class Time
    {
        private System.Timers.Timer prox;
        public Time(){
            prox = new System.Timers.Timer();
        }
    }
}
```

My project is a universal windows app.

Comment: Are you missing assembly references?

Comment: Can you provide the specific error with a screenshot?

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Timers' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Arcade\Game\Game.Windows\Time.cs 11 24 Game.Windows

Comment: add a timer control to your form

Comment: universal apps use DispatcherTimers, but probably one from a different namespace than the one in SWT.